# Spring Roo @Id field not populated in DataOnDemand test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, spring-roo

I am working with a web application built on Spring Roo 1.0.2.  I have defined an entity that has a primary key PERSONID column as well as several other fields.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "PERSONID", precision = 10, scale = 0)    
private Long personId;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "NAME")
@NotNull
private String name;

...
```

The Roo-managed integration tests contain a function that instantiates a mock object and populates each of the non-Id fields.

```
public Person PersonDataOnDemand.getNewTransientPerson(int index) {
    Person obj = new Person();    
    obj.setName("name_" + index);

    //set other non-Id fields

    return obj;
}
```

This function is called from integration tests and subsequently fails as the database table has a not null constraint on the PERSONID column.  I have tried explicitly setting the @NotNull annotation on the personId column, but it has no effect.  I suspect this has something to do with the fact that PERSONID is a non-autogenerated primary key.

I know I can address this by overriding the integration tests and populating the Id myself, but I would like to avoid this if possible.  Does anyone know a way that I can get this field automatically populated in the managed DataOnDemand objects?

Comment: In "normal" case Spring Roo create its own ID fields in one of its aspects (i belive in xx_entity.aj) - Did you have deactived the roo manged ID field? -- And would it work if you use the roo managed id?

Comment: @Ralph - thanks, you were correct.  As soon as I removed the @Id annotation, the _entity.aj aspect received a new managed @Id field and getNewTransientPerson populated the PersonId field.  Unfortunately, in my case, I do not have control over the DB schema, so I cannot use a managed primary key :(.  It looks like I will need to override the tests and populate the PersonId field manually.

Comment: You could try to do it the Roo way, by using @RooEntity.identifierColumn  -- i have never used this field before - but I excpect that this is what you need.

Comment: @Ralph - setting the identifierColumn property added an @Id field to the Entity aspect which was mapped to my PERSONID column, and the DataOnDemand aspect populated the field correctly. However, the PERSONID definition in the Entity aspect contains GenerationType.AUTO, resulting in an autogenerated value in the DB when I need it to be supplied by the user.  I found http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=297476#post297476, and it seems that then test generation is designed for sequential PKs.  Thanks for your help, if you post an answer I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Roo gerates it own ID field, in its _entity.aj aspect. So no extra field marked with @ID is needed in the "base"-class.
The Roo managed ID field should be populated by Roo's DataOnDemand.

The data base column for the roo managed id is "id" by default. If you need an other colum name (for example to match the database schema) then the column could be specified by the `@RooEntity.identifierColumn`.